# How to customize Display items by outputField's Link

Tags: visualforce

I want to know how to customize Display items on apex:outputField's Link.

1, I put apex:outputField on Visualforce Page.
2, I hover(Mouse-Over) this link, it display some items.

I want to customize this item, can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want to customize the fields in the popup window?

Comment: yes ! It showed as popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is known as the "Mini-page layout".  You can edit this when you are editing the object's standard page layout -- at the top right of the editing screen, there should be a link for Mini-page layout.  See [KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005180&type=1).

[image]

Comment: I see ! I can edit display items!
 Thank you so much!